# wpa_gui not finding wifi adapter while iwlist does successfully

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, wpa-supplicant

Using Ubuntu focal lts server edition. I manually installed Xorg.

I have a new install on my Dell XPS 7590. I want a light weight wifi manager so I installed wpa_supplicant and wpa_gui. I can run `sudo iwlist wlp58s0 scan` with no issues...it will show a list of wifi connection points successfully.

However, when I run `sudo wpa_gui` the GUI shows no network adapter. Any ideas on how to get wpa_gui running?

The wifi hardware is Wi-Fi 6 AX200 by Intel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wpa_gui` works by connecting to an instance of `wpa_supplicant` for a particular adapter. Let's see if this works -

**1.** Stop your currently running instance of `wpa_supplicant` with

```
$ sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant
```

**2.** Create a file `wpa_supplicant.conf` with the following

```
# /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
```

**3.** Startup `wpa_supplicant` specifying your interface name and your conf file

```
$ sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp58s0
```

**4.** Startup wpa_gui as root

```
$ sudo wpa_gui
```

And you should see `wlp58s0` as the interface. Automating this completely depends on the rest of your networking setup. You could make your own `systemd` service or modify the default one for `wpa_supplicant`, you could add some lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`, or you also achieve this with `netplan`.